# How to match regex with special characters ",( in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I generated following string after reading file.

> "The approach of neural computing is to capture the guiding principles that underly the brain's solution to these problems and apply them to computer systems." ( :14 ) "1.2 THE STRUCTURE OF THE BRAIN" ( :16 ) "brain at a low level. It contains approximately ten thousand million (10") basic units, called neurons. Each of these neurons is connected to about ten thousand (lo4) others." ( :16 )

What pattern I want to match looks like this: `"string" ( :digit+ )`

Its output will be:

> The approach of neural computing is to capture the guiding principles that underly the brain's solution to these problems and apply them to computer systems.
>   1.2 THE STRUCTURE OF THE BRAIN
>   brain at a low level. It contains approximately ten thousand million (10") basic units, called neurons. Each of these neurons is connected to about ten thousand (lo4) others.

I am new to regular expression. I have used

```
var reg = new Regex("\".*?\"");
```

It can match content within double quotation but how i can match rest of pattern?

Comment: Put a backslash before every special character to escape them when matching a text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to break this down into what you want the regex to do. Since you want to capture different groups, you'd surround them in parentheses:

You want to match on:

a quote
followed by anything that isn't a quote, one or more times; capture this as a group
followed by a quote
followed by parentheses
followed by colon
followed by a number, one or more times
followed by parentheses

```
string reg = "\"([^\"]+)\" \\( :\\d+ \\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correct, you need to detect all ( :digit )

```
string regex = "(\()(.){1}(:)[1-9]{1,}(.){1}(\))"
```

you can try it here: 
http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
  @ allows putting quotes in a string. So you can use this
  in regex search pattern.

  var st = @" ""1.2 THE STRUCTURE OF THE BRAIN"" (:15) )";

            List<string> result = new List<string>
                                (Regex.Matches(st, @" ""\d+\.\d+[\w\s]+""\s+\(:\d+\)")
                                .Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(x => x.Value)
                                .ToList());

            //  "1.2 THE STRUCTURE OF THE BRAIN" (:15)

    ""\d+\.\d+[\w\s]+"" ===>  "1.2 THE STRUCTURE OF THE BRAIN"
    \s+\(:\d+\)         ===>  (:15)
```